# Android intent sending data

Tags: android

Here is my button click listener

```
   go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Tab for Photos
            go();
            //photospec.setIndicator(url.getHost().replace("www."," ").replace(".com"," "));
        }
    });
```

Here is my go() method

```
public void go(){
         photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("");
            // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        // Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
        // intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
         //startActivity(intent)
         URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL( text.getText().toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        photospec.setIndicator(url.getHost().replace("www."," ").replace(".com"," "));
        photosIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),PhotosActivity.class);
        //photosIntent.setClass(this, PhotosActivity.class);
        photosIntent.putExtra("URL1", text.getText().toString());
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);


            if(counter==0){

            tabHost.addTab(photospec);
            }
            counter++;

    }
```

I have a button click method in this method I am calling function which name is `go()` in

this `go()` method ,I am creating a tab and i have intent. In this intent I am sending some

information to another class.

Problem is when I click button first time I can send data to another class normally. However when I click twice or more times this intent does not send data to other class.

Comment: What exactly do you mean send data to other class? Open another tab, or refresh tab `photospec`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you ask `counter==0`, and then increment that counter. The next time the code `tabHost.addTab(photospec)` won't be called, unless i'm missing something here.

How about this:

```
public void go(){
    TabHost.TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("");
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL( text.getText().toString()); 
        photospec.setIndicator(url.getHost().replace("www."," ").replace(".com"," "));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),PhotosActivity.class);
        photosIntent.putExtra("URL1", text.getText().toString());
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);
        tabHost.addTab(photospec);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```